# Future Plasma-Scramjet engines: If/how they could be used in the launching of spacecraft

Tags: future-missions, stages, sub-orbital, launch-system, ramjet

Recently I took a look at this paper:

> “Electrically Driven Supersonic Combustion”, Energies 2018, 11, 1733; doi:10.3390/en11071733 https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/11/7/1733 [image: This shows how a Plasma_Scramjet engine could operate at extremely high altitudes and Mach numbers.]

It made me think about how this might be used as a stage for a rocket that could bring it to a very high velocity, and a sub orbital trajectory. From what I understand this could allow for a much smaller first stage as well as a second stage that could build up a good deal of velocity at a lower altitude without the need for oxidizer along with less propellant. (Please correct me on any misunderstandings or ignorance on that.)

If this Plasma Scramjet was capable of being used as a stage for a spacecraft what would it look like? For example, could a smaller booster be used to accelerate it up to its working velocity and altitude? after which the Plasma Scramjet would be able to add accelerate the craft to a higher speed at a shallower angle. If this was done; (Hypothetically, not necessarily if this is simpler or cheaper) how would the actual craft have to be designed differently from a conventional rocket?

On an extra note, if anyone wants to answer a related question. Does this engine have the potential to make sub-orbital high speed commercial flights financially viable? Could we expect to have access to high speed transcontinental flights in minutes rather than hours in the *near* future?

Comment: @Fred thx for the grammar edit. It's hard to see everything clearly on my phone

Comment: That's a whole lot of questions there.

Comment: If you accelerate to near-orbital speeds within the atmosphere you get exactly the same things happening as when an orbiting object re-enters the atmosphere. Nobody wants a rocket to burn up **on ascent**, nor to carry massive heat shields to prevent that. So I'm pretty doubtful that it will ever make sense for an engine that uses atmospheric oxidizer to "build up to incredible orbital velocity at a lower altitude". Getting out of the atmosphere and getting a bit of a "kick": perhaps; getting a large chunk of orbital velocity: no.

Comment: @Ben Ok, a little kick then. so something like a second stage. Perhaps just to add some velocity horizontally and maybe even reduce the Max-Q and allow a more efficient upper stage. that could open the door for something like an orbital slingshot for an even more efficient upper stage.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sorry about that. Do you think I should split it up, or reduce the scope of the questions? Maybe asking how it could affect the launch profile alone would be enough to ascertain the possible integration with other future space travel technologies.

Comment: Maybe focus at first on whether it would even work as part of a booster: spoiler alert, it's pretty unlikely. If you could add an actual link to the paper, that would also be nice.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I followed your advice, do you think it's a bit more manageable and succinct? Are there any other changes I should make?

Comment: Thanks for the link - I skimmed the paper, but I didn't see any values for thrust or specific impulse, so I don't see how anyone could evaluate the usefulness of this engine for booster use based on that paper.

Comment: @OrganicMarble They do give information on fuel flow rate, pressures, and temperature of the exhaust. I'm not sure how to use those to calculate the actual thrust from those parameters, I never really learned magnetoplasmothermodynamics though lmao. This citation in the paper does go into a bit more details on the fuel flow rates, the conditions inside the combustion chamber and the exhaust products and their energy. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsta.2014.0337 I will just say that if I knew the thrust, Isp, and overall weight I doubt I would even need to ask this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of the sub questions are answered across the [air launch](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-launch) tag category - short version being for any useful rocket your lift aircraft is [massive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_Stratolaunch) and very [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_D-21#Testing_and_carrier_change), some napkin math suggests a falcon 9 first stage equivalent aircraft being sports stadium sized with the details just changing 'which sport'.

Looking at what plasma ignition does, it is solving just one of many problems with hypersonic flight, allowing you to sustain stable combustion at higher speed/altitude combinations. It does NOT solve intake geometry, heat removal or low speed issues and it does so consuming massive amounts of energy. kW and MW are mentioned in the paper alongside 2 percent of combustion energy. This is both a 2% performance hit and a requirement to generate massive amounts of electrical energy in your rocket plane, possibly 100MW which is decent terrestrial power station. Worse this is into an aggressively varying load (it is arcing BY DESIGN) so a challenging design where most of your failure modes involve an explosion, either in the electrical system or the suddenly unstable scramjet.

So at time of writing it is an interesting method to confront one scramjet design challenge, but only one challenge of many so premature to talk design details of an actual vehicle using it.